# PrintWriter to multiple files

Tags: java

I need to write the same text to multiple files (or streams).
Sometimes I need to use Writer, sometimes a PrintWriter, sometimes a OutputStream...

One way to do this wold be to extend a PrintWriter to have an array of PrintWriters and overridde each method as follows:

```
class MutiplePrintWriter extends PrintWriter {
    private PrintWriter[] outs;
    public MutiplePrintWriter(PrintWriter[] outs) { this.out = out; }

    public void print(boolean b) { for (PrintWriter out : outs) print(b); }
    public void print(char c) { for (PrintWriter out : outs) print(c); }
    public void print(char[] s) { for (PrintWriter out : outs) print(s); }
    ...
}
```

(and the same for Writer, OutputStream...)

Is there a better alternative?
Is this already implemented in a library?

Comment: Simple solution is often the best :)

Comment: **NOTE NOTE NOTE: DANGER: YOU DO NOT COPY THE ARRAY**. If the caller MODIFIES the array, you won't print where you expect! (or even insert a `null`: boom, NPE) Use `Arrays.copyOf(out, out.length)` on init! Oh, and you should check for null arguments too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are libraries out there already for this. If you can use OSS then grab [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) and take a look at the [TeeOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html) class. Here's some sample code illustrating its use:

```
public class TeeOutputStreamTest {

   @Test
   public void testPrintToMultipleStreams() throws Exception {
      final String fileName1 = "/tmp/fileOne.txt";
      final String fileName2 = "/tmp/fileTwo.txt";
      final String fileName3 = "/tmp/fileThree.txt";

      final TeeOutputStream tos = new TeeOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
              fileName1), new TeeOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName2),
              new FileOutputStream(fileName3)));
      final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(tos);

      writer.println("Hello World");
      writer.close();
   }
}
```

You can use `TeeOutputStream` anywhere a regular `OutputStream` is accepted, or wrap it in a `Writer`, depending on whats needed.

Comment: that's what i was looking for. is there also an equivalent for Writer and PrintWriter? I could use new FileWriter(new TeeOutputStream(...)), but the point is that FileWrite(OutputStream) does not allow to specify a charset. And FileOutputStream neither. so, where should I specify the charset, if using new FileWriter(new TeeOutputStream(...)) ?

Comment: @DavidPortabella - you can use an [`OutputStreamWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) if you want to specify a charset. Which can then of course be wrapped in a PrintWriter (or other Writer class, as the case requires).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to override all methods in `PrintWriter`, since all `printXyz` methods delegate to the basic `write` methods of the `Writer` API.

Although: `PrintWriter` has a constructor `PrintWriter(Writer out)`. So you need to implement only a new `Writer` with _one_method likes this:

```
public class MultiWriter implements Writer {
    private List<Writer> delegates;

    public MultiWriter(List<Writer> delegates){
        this.delegates = delegates;
    }

    public void write(char cbuf[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
        for(Writer w: delegates){
            w.writer(cbuf, off, len);
        }
    }
}
```

use this like this:

```
PrintWriter myPrinter = new PrintWriter(new MultiWriter(listOfDelegates));
myPrintWriter.println("Hello World!");
```

This will take care of the `Writers`.

You can do the same trick using `OutputStream`. You can also just implement `MultiOutputStream`, omit `MultiWriter` and use a delegation chain `PrintWriter->OutputStreamWriter->MultiOutputStream`. This would be just one method in one class to implement and you get `PrintWriter`, `Writer` and `OutputStream` just for free.

Answer (score 1):

## If you can use a Logging Library...

Use a logging library and define multiple appenders in its configuration.

You could use [Apache Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) or [LogBack](http://logback.qos.ch/) to that effect (I'd recommend LogBack, but to each their own).

## If you are forced to use PrintWriter...

The unfortunately your solution is the best.

There's an alternative, but it's not pretty. If you are forced to pass a PrintWriter, short of providing an extension to add to the JRE's trusted libs at load time to **replace** `PrintWriter` with a class doing in effect what you suggest, I don't think you have much choice.

Comment: I don't want to add a prefix for each line (like timestamp). even if that is configurable, it's an overkill to do that; and finally, I need to pass a "PrintWriter" to our existing APIs which I cannot modify.

Comment: @DavidPortabella: Those libs don't necessarily enforce crazy lines, they just do it by default to be nice. You can indeed remove those. But fine, I'll work on something with PrintWriter. Sorry for assuming your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually you *could* do this easily:

instead of overriding all methods of `PrintWriter` class, you could override **only one method** of class `Writer`:

```
public void write(char cbuf[], int off, int len);
```

because all other methods (`print(...)` and other `write(...)`-s) use this one:

```
public void write(char cbuf[], int off, int len) {
   for (Writer out : outs) out.write(cbuf, off, len);
}
```

**UPD:** also `flush()` and `close()` methods.

For `OutputStream` the same situation with method `public void write(int b)`

Comment: @haylem really? Have you checked this statement through java sources of appropriate classes?

Comment: yeah. but what I misread was your answer :) I didn't notice you meant to override `Writer`, not `PrintWriter`. I removed my comment to avoid confusion since.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer composition to extension.  Here is another option:

```
public class MultiWriter
{
    List<PrintWriter> listPrintWriter = new LinkedList<PrintWriter>;
    List<Writer> listWriter = new LinkedList<Writer>;

    public void addPrintWriter(final PrintWriter newPrintWriter)
    {
        listPrintWriter.add(newPrintWriter);
    }

    public void addWriter(final Writer newWriter)
    {
        listWriter.add(newWriter);
    }

    public void write((char cbuf[], int off, int len)
    {
        if (listPrintWriter != null)
        {
            for (PrintWriter printWriter : listPrintWriter)
            {
                printWriter.write(cbuf, off, len);
            }
        }

        if (listWriter != null)
        {
            for (Writer writer : listWriter)
            {
                writer.write(cbuf, off, len);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why a `LinkedList`? You only need to walk it one way, don't you?

Comment: linked list = no random access, fast append, fast iterate.